# What plane was this hotel room converted from?

Tags: aircraft-identification

The below image is of a converted aircraft now functioning as a hotel of sorts. 
I am having trouble identifying the type of the aircraft. [It is not on the listing](https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/1405703?guests=1&adults=1) page either. Does anyone know what aircraft this was?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [Gulfstream G2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_Gulfstream_II) corporate jet.